# Flask/Mongo/Jinja - Slicing a ListField and showing the last entries of the database

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, jinja2, database

I have a list with 12 categories inside an object, I want to get the first 3 itens of this list and show only the last entry of the database of each one of these 3 itens. What am I doing wrong? I can't take take only the last entries of 3 specific categories...

This is my app.py (not working!):

```
# try and get experiences where mood_name is inside the mood list
try:
    experiences = models.Experience.objects(mood=mood_name)

except:
    abort(404)

# get the first 3 interests inside Experience
ints = models.Experience.objects.fields(slice__interest=[0,2])

interest = ()

for i in ints:

    interest = 'i'
    # get the last experience of a specific interest
    exp_highlight = models.Experience.objects(interest=interest).order_by('-timestamp')
```

And this is my HTML/Jinja (not working):

```
{% for experience in experiences if experience.mood == 'Chill' %}
          {% if loop.index <= 2 %}

          <div class="item">
            <img class="image-highlight" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aliceapp/{{experience.filename}}"/>

              <div id="purple-small-box">
                <h6>{{ experience.interest }}</h6>
              </div>

                <div class="small-boxes">
                  <h3>{{ experience.title }}</h3>
                  <p>{{ experience.description }}</p>
                </div>
          </div>

          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
interest = 'i'
```

You probably want something like

```
interest = str(i)
```

or even

```
interest = i
```

Otherwise your lookup is going to look for objects where interest is 'i' instead of some number.